# .net cad: Import dimension style from another drawing

Tags: .net, cad

I need to improt dimension styles from dwg file by C#. I didn't find the answer online. Does anyone have an example? Say thank you in advance.

Comment: what is dwg file?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. It is A file format of AutoCAD.

Comment: ok my bad......

Comment: What .NET tool are you using to read DWG files?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved the problem. I'll paste the answer in later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution

```
internal static bool ImportDimensionStyleFromFile(string sourceCADFilePath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(sourceCADFilePath))
        {
            Document currentDoc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            Database currentDb = currentDoc.Database;
            Database sourceDb = new Database(false, true);
            using (sourceDb)
            {
                string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sourceCADFilePath);
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceCADFilePath);  //use fileName as blockName.
                try
                {
                    if (fileExtension == ".dxf")
                        sourceDb.DxfIn(sourceCADFilePath, null);
                    else if (fileExtension == ".dwg")
                        sourceDb.ReadDwgFile(sourceCADFilePath, FileOpenMode.OpenForReadAndReadShare, false, null);
                    else
                    {

                        return false;
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception)
                {

                    return false;
                }

                ObjectIdCollection idsForInsert = new ObjectIdCollection();
                using (Transaction acTrans = currentDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    DimStyleTable acDimTable = acTrans.GetObject(currentDb.DimStyleTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as DimStyleTable;
                    using (Transaction scTrans = sourceDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                    {
                        DimStyleTable scDimStyleTable = scTrans.GetObject(sourceDb.DimStyleTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as DimStyleTable;

                        foreach (ObjectId id in scDimStyleTable)
                        {
                            DimStyleTableRecord scStyleRecord = (DimStyleTableRecord)scTrans.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);
                            if (scStyleRecord != null && acDimTable.Has(scStyleRecord.Name) == false)
                            {
                                idsForInsert.Add(id);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (idsForInsert.Count != 0)
                    {
                        IdMapping iMap = new IdMapping();
                        currentDb.WblockCloneObjects(idsForInsert, currentDb.DimStyleTableId, iMap, DuplicateRecordCloning.Ignore, false);
                    }
                    acTrans.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```